# Multidimensional PyMC3 Observations

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, imputation

My model has a LogNormal RV, C, of shape (W,D). Each row in W and each column in D has a parameter that is being fit. I have tried to specify my observations as a (W,D) matrix, however, that is leading to a theano compile error

```py
raise Exception('Compilation failed (return status=%s): %s' %
Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Alloc(Elemwise{switch,no_inplace}.0, TensorConstant{10}, TensorConstant{10}), '\n', 'Compilation failed (return status=3): ', '[Alloc(<TensorType(float64, row)>, TensorConstant{10}, TensorConstant{10})]')
```

The model I am using is from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407008/summing-rvs-using-pymc3). The model along with the along with the observed data is below:

```py
logloss = np.array([[6.85856503, 6.35784227, 7.15773548, 6.7262334 , 4.34380542,
        4.68213123, 4.20469262, 2.07944154, 1.38629436, 0.        ],
       [6.74405919, 6.57228254, 6.45833828, 5.43807931, 3.58351894,
        2.94443898, 3.25809654, 2.56494936, 1.60943791,        nan],
       [6.89060912, 7.11314211, 6.42810527, 6.90975328, 5.33271879,
        3.25809654, 3.61091791, 3.97029191,        nan,        nan],
       [7.41276402, 6.93537045, 6.18208491, 6.06610809, 5.70378247,
        6.04025471, 2.48490665,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [6.83733281, 6.91572345, 6.53087763, 6.55961524, 3.58351894,
        4.81218436,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [7.05789794, 7.12286666, 5.98393628, 5.28320373, 3.63758616,
               nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [7.2984451 , 7.31455283, 6.8721281 , 6.64509097,        nan,
               nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [7.12286666, 6.73340189, 6.26720055,        nan,        nan,
               nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [7.18992217, 6.9902565 ,        nan,        nan,        nan,
               nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [7.25347038,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,
               nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan]])

logprem = np.array([8.66768002, 8.49862181, 8.60410456, 8.54966038, 8.55910259,
       8.56216656, 8.51559191, 8.60630237, 8.56140145, 8.50956416])

D = 10
W = 10

logprem = tt._shared(logprem).T.repeat(D, axis=1))

with pm.Model() as model:
    logelr = pm.Normal('logelr', -0.4, np.sqrt(10))

    # col vector
    alpha = pm.Normal("alpha", 0, sigma=np.sqrt(10), shape=(W-1,1))

    # row vector
    beta = pm.Normal("beta", 0, sigma=np.sqrt(10), shape=(1,D-1))

    # prepend zero and broadcast to (W,D)
    alpha_aug = tt.concatenate([tt.zeros((1,1)), alpha], axis=0).repeat(D, axis=1)

    # append zero and broadcast to (W,D)
    beta_aug = tt.concatenate([beta, tt.zeros((1,1))], axis=1).repeat(W, axis=0)

    # technically the indices will be reversed
    # e.g., a[0], a[9] here correspond to a_10, a_1 in the paper, resp.
    a = pm.Uniform('a', 0, 1, shape=D)

    # Note: the [::-1] sorts it in the order specified 
    # such that (sigma_0 > sigma_1 > ... )
    sigma = pm.Deterministic('sigma', tt.extra_ops.cumsum(a)[::-1].reshape((1,D)))

    # now everything here has shape (W,D) or is scalar (logelr)
    mu = logprem + logelr + alpha_aug + beta_aug

    # sigma will be broadcast automatically
    C = pm.Lognormal('C', mu=mu, sigma=sigma, shape=(W,D), observed=logloss)
```

Comment: what's up with the nan's? Is there really only one (partial) observation of the matrix? It might help if you pointed out where this model came from.

Comment: Sure, this is a model for actuarial claims reserving. Each row would be an accident year and each column is a development age. The most recent accident year will only have 1 period of development, the second most recent will have two period of development, etc. The objective would be to "square the triangle" by filling in the nans. The paper describing the model is [here](https://www.casact.org/pubs/monographs/index.cfm?fa=meyers-monograph08), specifically Section 5 of the paper, The Cross Classified Model

Comment: The immediate issue can be solved by converting `logloss` to a tensor, either with `tt._shared` or moving it under the model context and using `pm.Data()`. The larger issue however, is that observed variables only evaluate likelihoods, so if you want imputation of `C`, you need to sample it without the observed and separately evaluate the likelihood of the actual observed values. Also, PyMC3 doesn't handle the nan's - not sure the best work around for that.